# Database - Normalize a table that is missing a primary key?

Tags: sql, database, key, primary-key, normalize

I have been given a (school) task where I need to normalize this table (with 3NF): https://i.imgur.com/SPNzhrC.png

I have read a bit about normalization and as far as I have understood a table NEEDS to have a primary key in order to be normalized but in this case I fail to identify any sort of primary key. It seems like it does not have any (since no column values are unique, not even "Drug Number"). So how do I normalize this table then? I feel like I am missing something fairly obvious here.

Comment: You will make a primary key that is autoincrement for you `patient` table, `drug` table (where you can use the drug number instead), and `patient-drug` table with appropriate foreign key relationships and all that fun stuff. Drug numbers ARE unique here. `Morphine` is `10223`. That is 1 record in your `drug` table. It will end up as two records in your `patient-drug` table and `patient-drug` has an autoincrement key, or a compound key on `patient_id | drug_id | finish_date` or something ugly like that.

Comment: @JNevill When you say "patient-drug table" you are talking about the table in the picture right? Are you saying that I should split it up into 3 tables, "patient-drug", "patient" and "drug" tables? PatientID is not an attribute in the "patient drug" table in my eyes because each patient seems to have a separate table for medication. I have never done normalization before. Can you give me an example of what this would look like?

Comment: there are no tables in the picture. Only a form. I would extrapolate from that form the table structure necessary to support it. You could do it all in one table, but that would be a poor choice. Two tables (`patient` and `drug`) wouldn't be great either as you would have to either repeat `patient` records for each patient to insure that their 1:many drugs are listed as well as well as the date range for which they are administered. A third table `patient-drug` instead can provide the link here. `pd_id | patient_id | drug_id | start_date | finish_date `.

Comment: It helps here to think of a "relationship` as a distinct object. You have a `drug` and a `patient` and a relationship between them, so three tables. This relationship has it's own attributes besides the two objects in the relationship, in this case `start_date` and `end_date` (and probably also `dosage` and `method of admin` and `units per day`) depending on where those make the most sense. Is `method of admin` particular to the drug (is morphine ALWAYS administered orally) or is it particular to the patient-drug relationship (currently giving patient morphine orally, but next time through IV)

Comment: @JNevill I have thought about that myself and nowhere in the task does it specify if a drug has a unique MoA (method of administration).

Comment: I feel like the `patient-drug` table or perhaps more aptly called `drugs_administered` would then be `da_id (autoincrement) | patient_id | drug_id | dosage | method_of_admin | units_per_day | start_date | end_date` with foreign keys on `drug_id` and `patient_id` and their respective tables.

Comment: You can further normalize here by sticking `method_of_admin` in it's own table with `method_id | method_text ` and then the `method_id` would be stored in the `drugs_administered` table with foreign key. `dosage` could be split into two fields `dosage_amount | dosage_unit ` and then `dosage_unit` could be in its own table. I think that's overkill, but.. it just depends on how deep you want the rabbit hole to go.

Comment: @JNevill I am thinking about keeping it at 3 tables but adding dosage in the drug table instead of it having its own table. Since, in my mind, each drug has a unique dosage/strength. Would that work?

Comment: I agree that three tables would be sufficient here. I feel like `dosage` would be an attribute of the `drugs_administered` (`patient-drug`) table as each time the drug is administered it might be at a different dosage. I'm totally making some major assumptions from your screen shot though :) You do what feels right here.

Comment: @JNevill I view the dosage as "strength per pill" (in mg, you know the little text that is written on the side of pill bottles). Isn't it "unit per day" that defines how much medicine a patient would get (per day)?

Comment: @JNevill I made a quick diagram of how this would look like: https://i.imgur.com/gjDN2Tn.png . Is this fine? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Yes. Your idea of dosage makes sense to me. Your diagram looks good to me too:) Hope it gets a passing grade. I feel responsible now.

Comment: @JNevill Thanks for helping me out man! Never would have figured this out on my own :)